# как устранить утечку памяти в этом коде?

Tags: javascript, утечка-памяти

```js
var theItem = null;
var replaceItem = function() {
  var priorItem = theItem;
  var writeToLog = function() {
    if (priorItem) {
      console.log("hi");
    }
  };
  theItem = {
    longStr: new Array(1000000).join('*'),
    someMethod: function() {
      console.log(someMessage);
    }
  };
};

setInterval(replaceItem, 1000);
```

Comment: а почему ты думаешь, что тут будет утечка?

Comment: Не писать такие странные функции. Не создавать функции в цикле.

Comment: Конкретно это синтетический пример и чинить его бессмысленно. В реальности надо будет смотреть зачем нужен someMethod и, наверное, просто не создавать его каждый раз, а вынести наружу.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, а что не так с `someMethod`?

Comment: @Grundy у него в замыкании есть priorItem и он может получить доступ к priorItem.longStr, значит эта строка продолжает жить. А так же есть доступ к priorItem.someMethod и далее вверх по рекурсии. Кажется современные движки умеют конкретно такой случай оптимизировать, но в общем случае gc не имеет права удалить все эти мегабайтные строки т.к. к ним есть доступ

Comment: @AlexeyTen, рекурсии нет, вполне имеет права, так как к ним никто не обращается.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86299/discussion-between-alexey-ten-and-grundy).